# Demonstration of a basic formula involving differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

I'm writing some notes on Lie Groups and I'm not sure if I should demonstrate this formula or not. Assume $\omega$ is a differencial form and $X,Y$ fields con a Manifold M, is there a simple way to demonstrate that
$$d\omega(X,Y)=X\left(\omega\left(Y\right)\right)-Y\left(\omega\left(X\right)\right)-\omega\left(\left[X,Y\right]\right)$$

Comment: May I ask what your definition of $d\omega$ is? As I sometimes took this formula as the definition. :P

Comment: @awllower Probably the local coordinate expression. In this case, the argument is very short. Locally we can write $\omega$ as a sum of terms $f \,dg$ for some smooth functions $f, g$, so by linearity it suffices to prove the claim for a single form of this form. Then, just write both sides in terms of $f, g$ and their directional derivates $X \cdot f$, etc.

Comment: I have just written down a detailed calculation for this yesterday in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804895/let-theta-a-1-form-why-d-thetax-y-x-thetay-y-thetax-thetax-y/1804974#1804974). This is a straight-forward computation, and the question of if you can compute this faster comes down to how well you understand 1-forms and which parts of the computation you consider to be clear.

Comment: Your formula should have $d\omega(X,Y)$ on the left hand side.

Comment: yes indeed altough it was clear from the context that was evaluated on the vector fields $X$ and $Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That formula is often used as the definition! Since you're asking this question, I'll assume you're using the other common definition of $d$ for one-forms, which is the coordinate formula $d\omega_{ij} = \partial_i \omega_j - \partial_j \omega_i.$  Contracting with $X^i Y^j$ we get $$d \omega(X,Y) = Y^j X(\omega_j) - X^j Y(\omega_j).$$

From the Leibniz rule we have $ Y^j X(\omega_j)  = X(\omega_j Y^j) - \omega_j X(Y^j)$ and similarly for the other term, so we get

$$ d \omega(X,Y) = X(\omega(Y)) - Y(\omega(X)) -\omega_j (X(Y^j) - Y(X^j)).$$

Recognizing the last term as $\omega([X,Y])$ we have the desired formula.

Comment: Indeed you perfectly caught the spirit of my question. thanx